# Functional data processing in clojure

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, architecture

I'm looking for some architectural solution to the problem I'm facing.
I am struggling with a huge pipeline that processes `data` (which is a very complex structure). Generally, it can be illustrated as:

```
(defn process [data]
  (-> data
    do-something-1
    do-something-2
    do-something-3
    do-something-4
    ...
    do-something-20
)
```

where each of the `do-something-*` functions might be similarly complex.
My problem is that there is a lot of coupling between functions in such a processing chain. For example `do-something-3`add something to data that later is required by `do-something-9` which adds something else required by `do-something-18` and so on. So essentially data is enriched by all those functions when cascading down the threading macro. It's very hard to keep the track of what is happening and when. Holding the whole processing chain in my head is just too much of a cognitive load (or at least I have too little RAM in my head).
How do handle such cases? I get that there is no silver bullet but maybe there is something I'm missing (I started to learn clojure few months ago).

Comment: Besides general ideas (split data into smaller pieces you can work on independently, shorter chains with docs in between, etc.) one thing you could try using spec and to validate and document at various places in the pipeline. I don't have much experience with this, but it perhaps you could do data -> conform -> do-something-1 -> unform to give `do-something-1` a slightly simpler view.

Depending on the nature of the data, you could also home-roll functions to surround certain stages of the pipeline that "protect" that stage from the full complexity of the data.

Comment: Conceptually, you have a graph of data dependencies where each node is a function and each edge is a dependency (`do-something-9` depends on `do-something-3`). So, you can make that graph explicit by codifying and specifying what each function provides and what it depends on. You'll have to write some boilerplate around it, which might even exist already, but in the end you'll be able to use any graph tools with it, including for visualization.

Answer (score 1):

I have never liked long pipelines as you describe because of the difficulties you are encountering.

As a first step, you might just break up the pipeline and give a name (even if temporary) to each stage:

```
(defn process [data]
  (let [x01 (do-something-1 data)
        x02 (do-something-2 x01)
        x03 (do-something-3 x02)
        x04 (do-something-4 x03)
        ; ...
        x20 (do-something-20 x19)]
    x20))
```

Then, you could add debug and/or validation statements between as necessary. I would also suggest using Plumatic Schema to document the input/output of each `do-something-*` function (or maybe Malli; I don't like spec). Hopefully the function names are also descriptive; you could improve those as another plus.

You could also group the functions in a hierarchy instead of a just a linear chain:

```bash
A
 - A1
 - A2
 - A3
 - A4
B
 - B1 
 - B2
 - B3
C 
 ...etc...
```

So the top-level pipeline is only 3-4 calls, each of which may have 2-5 sub-calls.

Of course, I hope you have nice unit tests for each function at all levels to document the expected behavior and typical inputs/outputs.